# Random Integer, no repeat, within specific range

Tags: c#, string, random, generator

Detailed scenario:

There are 300 possible numbers that fit into the discription.

That is, the number must between 1123 and 5543 inclusive

The number is unique and not repeated

The number only has the integers 1,2,3,4 and 5.

What I am trying to achieve is a program that can display all those numbers at once in ascending order.

My current code:

```
var chars = "12345";
var stringChars = new char[4];
var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}
var finalString = new String(stringChars);
Console.WriteLine(finalString)
```

This code works fine, but I have 2 additional requirements.

1. Loop 300 times
2. Display all results in ascending order

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry for all confusion. What this code produces is a 4 digit number like I want. But I want to it to do so 300 times. I guess I can use a Loop, but this is my first time using C# (I've only used vb.net in the past). What I mean by random and in ascending order is: Produce a random number, and when all numbers are generated, order them in ascending order before displaying them all.

However, if ordering them will be too complicated, then I'm fine without that.

Comment: All you've provided so far is your specification. What is your _question_? What did you do by way of attempting to implement the specification, what did that code do, and how is that different from what you want it to do? Make sure you provide a good [mcve] showing all of this, along with a detailed explanation describing it.

Comment: You’ll have to ask a question otherwise we cannot help you. Also, **never use goto**

Comment: How can this be both random and in ascending order?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do you know there are 300 numbers between 1123 and 5543 consisting only of digits 1-5? By my count there are 611.

Comment: Generate all 300 in order. Put them in a list. Shuffle the list. There, now you have the 300 numbers in random order with no repeats.

Comment: @EricLippert Did you even read the question? I am very knew to C# and I already said I don't want them ordered anymore!

Comment: I did read the "question"; it is confusing, poorly written, and seems to not contain an actual question.

Comment: @USERNNNNN - You say "I don't want them ordered" and Eric said "random order". Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but here is some code that will print the 611 (not 300) numbers matching the description you gave in ascending order.

If I've understood your question correctly, you will want to sample 300 distinct elements from this larger set, sort them, and them print them out. You might look at using a Fisher-Yates shuffle to do this. Shuffle the list, take the first 300, and sort them.

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
  var digits = new [] { 1, 1, 2, 3 };
  for (var num = DigitsToInt(digits); num <= 5543; num = DigitsToInt(digits)) {
    Console.WriteLine(num);

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
      digits[i]++;
      if (digits[i] < 6) {
        break;
      } else {
        digits[i] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

private static int DigitsToInt(int[] digits) {
  return 1000 * digits[0] + 100 * digits[1] + 10 * digits[2] + digits[3];
}
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry, my bad, but I forgot another rule that is required and that is double digits ( I edited the question)

Comment: @USERNNNNN - Please don't change the question because you forgot something. Add an edit that appends to the question, but don't amend it.

Comment: @Enigmativity - why not? The question is only getting harder to understand the longer and more disjointed it gets. Replacing the current description with a clear, concise one is surely better, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexReinking - Clarifying a question is perfectly fine, but changing a question that invalidates existing answers isn't. If someone asked "what is the fastest animal?" and the answer of "peregrine falcon" is given, but then the OP says, "oh, I meant what is the fastest mammal?" then the falcon answerer looks pretty stupid.

Comment: Would you kindly please delete your answer? I have muffled up the question so I am going to delete it if you allow me by deleting your answer first.

Comment: Would you please delete your answer Alex, the question became cloudy and is no good for this site anymore.

Comment: @USERNNNNN - why would I delete my answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity - isn't that what the edit history is for? I agree dramatic rewrites late in the game are bad practice at best, but within a few hours of posting and little interaction, surely restructuring a question does more good than harm.

Comment: @AlexReinking - I disagree. If I have to look at the edit history to understand a question then it's become a poorly edited question. I also don't think that there is any time limit on restructuring. I think the rule is that if restructuring invalidates existing answers then it's too late to make such a change.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm confused by your statement: "If I have to look at the edit history to understand a question then it's become a poorly edited question". My whole argument here is that the question is _already_ difficult to understand. Replacing it with something crystal clear would save you from having to look at anything but the most recent version of the question. If the sole answerer (I) is (am) willing to update their (my) answer in response to the asker's changes (and I am), I see no reason the most-recent edit of a question shouldn't be as clear as possible.

Comment: @AlexReinking - As long as it doesn't make answers/comments inconsistent with the newly worded question then it's a problem.